# Upload files to dropbox with php - Dropbox-SDK-PHP

Tags: php

im a beginer and i traying to upload files to dropbox using [dropbox-sdk-php](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php)

this is the code that I am using

live test : http://test.dedragon.net

```html
$dropboxKey ='MY_KEY';
$dropboxSecret ='MY_SECRET';
$appName='MY_APPNAME';
$acessToken = "MY_ACCESTOKEN";
set_error_handler('error');

$appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);
//Store CSRF token
$csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION['k6'],'dropbox-auth');
//define auth details
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'http://test.dedragon.net',$csrfTokenStore);
$client = new Dropbox\client($acessToken,$appName,'UTF-8');

//time to upload file
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $nombre = uniqid();
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
         $f = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
        $ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $ext =end($ext);
        $nombredropbox = "/". $nombre .'.'.$ext;
        $tama = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['size']);

            try{
               $client->uploadFile($nombredropbox,Dropbox\WriteMode::add(),$f);
             }catch(Dropbox\Exception_InvalidAccessToken $e){
                 error('001',$e);
             }

}


function error($numero,$texto){
  $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
  fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."] Error $numero: $texto\r\n");
  fclose($ddf);
}
```

shows me Status Code: 500

and Error appear

```html
[05-Jun-2019 09:08:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest: HTTP status 400
{"error": "v1_retired"} in /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php:250
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/Client.php(558): Dropbox\RequestUtil::unexpectedStatus(Object(Dropbox\HttpResponse))
#1 /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/Client.php(423): Dropbox\Client->chunkedUploadStart('%PDF-1.5\r\n%\xB5\xB5\xB5\xB5...')
#2 /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php(279): Dropbox\Client->Dropbox\{closure}()
#3 /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/Client.php(424): Dropbox\RequestUtil::runWithRetry(3, Object(Closure))
#4 /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/Client.php(286): Dropbox\Client->_upload in /home/jjddqqslmq4q/public_html/test/terceros/dropbox/vendor/dropbox/dropbox-sdk/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php on line 250
[05-Jun-2019 09:11:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest: HTTP status 400
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: If it's live server then share URL

Comment: @Dhruv a link to the actual site shouldn't be needed, you won't get much more detail than OP with a error 500.

Comment: @Epodax you are right but on line number 9 he is mention localhost system path so i want to just check on live so i'm asking to live url because i want to review it

Comment: @Dhruv Hello here you have  http://test.dedragon.net/

Comment: Above file is your upload.php file ?

Comment: yes it is upload.php

Comment: The absolute first thing you _always_ do on an internal server error, is you go check the server’s error log!

Comment: On line number 9 why you mention "http://localhost"

Comment: srry 
I have not updated the code but that is the url which is used to redirect when you doenst have a token

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error which indicates a crash in your PHP code. It is deliberate vague to prevent accidentally leaking sensitive info to the browser in the error detail (e.g. database names, API keys or similar). Ensure that PHP error logging is switched on (you can google it) and then run your code again. Then check the error log to see what it says.

Comment: Also this: `}catch(Dropbox\Exception_InvalidAccessToken $e){
       Echo "Error";
  }` is a bad idea. You are basically catching an error and then discarding all the useful information about it. It's fine to hide the error from the user, but you need to at least log the details to disk so that you can investigate it later. Otherwise how are you ever going to know what went wrong?

Comment: @ADyson ty for the council , I have changed the code

Comment: Ok. using print_r() is fine for testing, but it would be better to log it to disk in the long term. Anyway, that was a separate point really. Since you have code for catching that particular exception, that can't be the cause of your 500 error. As I said you need to ensure error logging is switched on and then re-test, and then look at your logs.

Comment: @ADyson, I have written all the errors in a file .
then I have seen the file and there are several

Comment: I do not know if I can do this  

  $f = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

Comment: Ok so the error in your log says you're getting a HTTP 400 "Bad Request" response from the Dropbox API. A 400 Bad Request means they were unable to validate your request. The message within that, i.e. `"error": "v1_retired"` seems to me to be pretty clear. They have shut down version 1 of the API. A quick google search confirms it was shut down in 2017 (see https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/). This link describes that you'll get that exact 400 error with that exact message, if you try to use it.

Comment: I think you need to use a newer version of their API. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Comment: P.S. The GitHub link you gave (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php)  says **Do not use this SDK. It relies on Dropbox API v1, which is obsolete.** in bold text at the very top of the readme. Did you not notice this??? It's hard not to see it. Try to read things more carefully, because you've just wasted quite a lot of your time on something which will never work.

Comment: Fortunately if you also google "dropbox php sdk" you'll see that someone has been working on a PHP library for the Dropbox version 2 API, so that you don't have to make the raw HTTP requests yourself. See https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk . I have no idea how good it is, but it certainly exists and is worth investigating

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm going to take a look

Comment: thank you @ADyson  i found a solution in that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the SDK to https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk.

```html
<?php
require_once("terceros/dropbox/vendor/autoload.php");
use Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxFile;

$dropboxKey ='MY_KEY';
$dropboxSecret ='MY_SECRET';
$acessToken = "MY_TOKEN";

set_error_handler('error');

$app = new DropboxApp($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret,$acessToken);
$dropbox = new Dropbox($app);



if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $nombre = uniqid();
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $ext =end($ext);
        $nombredropbox = "/". $nombre .'.'.$ext;


            TRY{
                $file = $dropbox->simpleUpload($tempFile,$nombredropbox, ['autorename' => true]);
                //Uploaded File
             }CATCH(\EXCEPTION $E){
                 ERROR('001',$E);
             }


}


function error($numero,$texto){
  $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
  fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."] Error $numero: $texto\r\n");
  fclose($ddf);
}

 ?>
```